# Can `bazel test` call `bazel run`?

Tags: bazel

I'm writing an integration test for a script that calls `bazel run` (which produces a file in the source workspace). Ideally, the test can be called via `bazel test`.

I know `bazel test` creates a sandbox and have added `"//:WORKSPACE"` as a test data dependency.

And I was running into an issue with a setting in `~/.bazelrc` which led me to use `bazel --nohome_rc run` in the test. But now I'm getting `WORKSPACE file can not be a symlink if incrementally updated directories are used.`

Is it possible to have `bazel test` call `bazel run`? If so, how?

Comment: It's probably technically possible, but arguably it shouldn't be done.  Bazel constructs a static graph of all dependencies when invoked, and being able to call bazel run would mean the graph could become dynamic (or even cyclical).

Comment: I'm not sure how true that is since it looks like it should be possible for bazel to start a new context if run in a separate workspace. The downside would be that doing so could take a long time.

Comment: It's certainly possible, and bazel uses `bazel run` in its own integration tests: https://cs.opensource.google/search?q=%22bazel%20run%22%20f:%5C.sh%20f:test&ss=bazel%2Fbazel

however it's a pretty big maintenance burden, not very fast, and not generally / directly supported